# English for "Colegio de Arquitectos"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, modismos

What is a good English translation of [Colegio de Arquitectos y Arquitectos Paisajistas de Puerto Rico](http://www.caappr.org/)?

I simply said "College of Architects" until my friend notified me that *Colegio de Abogados* translates as **Bar Association** (though Google translate gives **Law School**).

Here we are referring to a *professional association* of architects and I did not have a good answer for her.  College of Architects sounded fine for me.

Comment: We actually translate one of the colegios as college in English: the College of Cardinals.  But given that colegio is a bit ambiguous (like "department" in English, given "Department of Homeland Security" and "Department of English", what would "Department of Criminal Justice" be?), it can either be School of, College of, or Association of, etc.

Comment: _College_ is an educational institution.

Comment: Is the Electoral College an educational institution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subject of the Spanish word `Colegio` is very interesting, due to the very known fact that its uses are spread along a very wide range of topics.

This is interesting not only in Spanish. Even when dealing with an association of professionals with the same title, when in Spanish almost always is used the word `Colegio`, in English we found ourselves with many options.

For Architects, I got this [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=college+of+architects%2Cassociation+of+architects%2Cinstitute+of+architects%2Carchitect%27s+association&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccollege%20of%20architects%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassociation%20of%20architects%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinstitute%20of%20architects%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carchitect%20%27s%20association%3B%2Cc0):

[image: GoogleNgram]

With this graph, it is clear that "Association of Architects" has been more used than "College of Architects".

According to what I found searching in Google, "**Association of Architects**" is indeed the most used form.

Comment: Except that in Puerto Rico, the word "colegio" implies that you are required to be a dues-paying member in order to practice your trade. That is slowly changing, though, because many of these organizations are really just political action groups in disguise and members do not like that.